# CakePHP use MS Access database (.mdb, not accdb): Do I need to write a driver? How to build it?

Tags: cakephp, ms-access, cakephp-2.0

I'm in the unlucky situation where my client requires to use a read-only MS Access database to render some webpage contents on his website (built by me).

Because this MS Access file will be updated roughly once per month and I don't want to do it manually by converting it into sql query and import in Mysql, I would like to make some webpages read directly from it.

What I discovered is that there isn't a driver (at least in my cakephp installation) for MS Access database (but in older versions of cake exist) or at least I didn't find any of them.

I need to know where eventually I can find such drivers or how to correctly implement one of them only for read operations (I think I should implement DboSource class, but I don't know what should I override because there isn't anything such *virtual* or *abstract* or *interface* that guide me through this).

I didn't even understand if I should create an Adodb driver or an OleDB driver. I also think that Sqlserver driver is a lot similar to what I should build (except for connectionand some details); if I can use it in some way to shorten my job, it will be helpful.

**Edit 1:**

Because no one is answering, I can say I'm ok to use MS Access also with "normal" queries (without requiring each table to be bound to a model) but I must be sure that are sanitized and will output arrays similar to what cakes output actually: *$jobs['jobs']['name']*

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Adodb or Odbc datasources from https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/2.0/Model/Datasource/Database work with MS Access?

Comment: I solved with this, editing the driver a bit because it's not completed at the moment, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This example is to big to write here it-s from [cake bakery](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/aspeakman/2008/12/29/a-cakephp-adodb-data-source-driver-for-ms-access)  Please test it and i'm here for other problems

Comment: *Error: Datasource class adodb could not be found.* Is what I get in cake bake command. Maybe I shouldn't try to create a model with cake console command but if that's the case, can you tell me how to make a query without a model? I never did it in cake.

Comment: First of all... i have a question. Why mdb? There are so many DB :) Anyway.. you need a driver. I will edit my first post.

Comment: Eh I written it on the first line of my question: *I'm in the unlucky situation where my client requires to use a read-only MS Access database to render some webpage contents on his website* so I can't do anything about it, it's a request. However I already read that article on the bakery and tried to make it works, but it's for 1.1 version of cakephp and DboAdodb class doesn't even exists anymore, so it can't work correctly, that's why I were asking how to write a driver.

Comment: Sry, i can't write a driver for a new version of cakephp. I don't have that skills. Can you convert mdb in mysql? That's help you?

Comment: No I can't convert because it should be done periodically (not by me so). But don't fear, I don't want you to do my job by writing the driver for me, I were just looking for guidelines that should be followed to write a driver (which function should I implement and so on). Thanks anyway for following my question