# cakephp and mdb database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need to create a site with cakephp 2.x with a mdb access database (It's a requirement for our client :( ).

I have seen already this question:

[CakePHP use MS Access database (.mdb, not accdb): Do I need to write a driver? How to build it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606959/cakephp-use-ms-access-database-mdb-not-accdb-do-i-need-to-write-a-driver-h)

But I haven't solved, I have download this plugin and installed:
https://github.com/cakephp/datasources

So I have edit my database.php in this way:

```
public $default = array(
        'driver' => 'Datasources.Database/AdoDb',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

But returns me this error:

```
Undefined index: datasource
CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
Datasource class could not be found.
```

I have tried in bootstrap.php this:

```
App::uses('Datasources', 'Datasources.Model/Datasource');
```

Can someone help me to access to my mdb database?
Thanks